# cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findviewbyid(int) TextView

Tags: android

i have this error
`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity" in a second activity`

Code of second activity:

```
public class sendQuery extends main  {
/////////// Public method to send Query ///////////
public static String send(String query,Activity main) {
    String result = "0";
    InputStream is = null;
    String weekDayVal=null;
    //the query to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> querySend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    querySend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("querySend",query));

    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://locali.altervista.org/php/locali.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(querySend));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        try{
            JSONArray weekDetails = new JSONArray ( result); // Your response string
            for(int index=0;index < weekDetails.length();index++)
            {
            JSONObject tempWeekDetail = weekDetails.getJSONObject(index);
            weekDayVal = tempWeekDetail.getString("Lunedi");// Value for Monday
            //added this Log which you can view from LogCat. also changed above variable name
            Log.i("Resp Value","Moday Value "+weekDayVal);
            }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

                TextView text = (TextView) main.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
                text.setText(weekDayVal);
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result: "+e.toString());
    }

    Log.i("SendQUERY", result);
    return result;
}
  }
```

Have I first to pass the value to main activity?
and why I get this error?
Please help me!
Thanks

EDIT

I have modify code, is now correct?   because I do not see the writing in the TextView

Answer (score 1):

You have declared this method to be static.

Your line of code

```
 TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
```

And this

```
findViewById(int id)
```

Is from the Activity class, which **requires** a instance of this class in order to use.

[Activity.findViewById(int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29)

**Solution**:

What you can do is adding a parameter to your method like:

```
public static String send(String query,Activity yourActivity)
```

then use

```
 TextView text = (TextView) yourActivity.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
```

Comment: This works, or, if it really does need to be static, I'd recommend just having the method return success or failure, and having the Activity instance handle updating its UI based on the result, rather than a static method modifying the Activity.

Comment: In my opinon the whole method itself shouldn't be static. Since its not my related to the question, we can't add any opinons to it.

Comment: You will need to post your error log. But this maybe out of scope of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have static method, you cann't call not static method. Static method "exists" without instance of class. Non static method is "part" of instance of class.

Pass View, in which you want to find View as parameter of the static method.

```
public static String send(String query, View view) {
   ....

   view.findViewById(R.id.some_id);
   ....
}
```